# rails db design for shop with multiple regions and multiple product variations

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I'm trying to wrap my head around this topic but can't find a simple solution.

- product based on region price.
- regions have one currency per region and stock per region.
- then there are product variations like color and size, color should be special cause I need images for it.
- color and size is depending on stock based on the region.
- product has one price per region

Maybe anyone here has a good idea for this db layout.

**edit**

### products

- id
- name
- identifier
- slug

### product_variations

- id
- product_id
- name
- size
- image

### product_stocks

- id
- count
- product_variation_id
- region_id

### product_prices

- id
- product_id
- region_id
- price

### regions

- id
- name
- slug

still the size is tied to the variations..
i need one variation with multiple sizes and stock should also be linkable to size based on region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like:

**`Products`**:

- `Id`.
- `Name`.

> product variations like color and size, colour.

**`ProductVariations`**:

- `Id`.
- `ProductId`.
- `StockId`(color and size is depending on stock based on the region)
- `Colour`.
- `Size`

> regions have one currency per region and stock per region.

**`Currencies`**:

- `Id`.
- `Name`.

**`Stocks`**:

- `Id`.
- `Name`.
- `RegionId`.

**`Regions`**:

- `Id`.
- `Name`.
- `CurrencyId`.
- `StockId`.

> product has one price per region
>
> product based on region price

**`ProductPrices`**:

- `Id`.
- `ProductId` -> Products table.
- `RegionId` -> Regions table.
- `Price`.

You might need to tweak this structure a little bit to accommodate:

- The product images depending on whether you need only one image per product or a product can have many images (new table `ProductImages`).
- You didn't clarify the product properties you need(product variations) are they a lot of variations for each product (one to many for each product) or its just a properties for each product.

**Update:**

> one size can have stock as well.

In this case you can move  `Colour` and `Size` or the `size` only as you want to a new table, something like, `ProductVariationOptions`:

**`ProductVariationOptions`**:

- `Id`.
- `Size`.
- `Colour`.

Then the your `ProductVariationOptions` would be like this:

**`ProductVariations`**:

- `Id`.
- `ProductId`.
- `StockId`(color and size is depending on stock based on the region)
- `ProductVariationOptionsId` -> `ProductVariationOptions`

Comment: thanks for your answer - what about sizes? one size can have stock as well.. what do you think of creating product_variations (would be the color) and a product_options table with key value (for size) and then in the product_stocks table product_variation_id (for no product_options) and product_option_id (for size stock)

Answer (score 1):

A region can have many products through variations

A variation can have multiple images

### Region

- name
- currency

### Product

- name

### Variation

- colors
- sizes
- price
- region_id
- product_id

### Images

- variation_id

For sizes and colors I would probably use the simple_enum gem.  I've been using it on a project that I have been working on and it has been pretty nice.